# SFML shader not working

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to create a outline effect to my buttons when they are clicked but atm I'm just testing stuff with shaders... whenever I draw something with my shader tho it renders the shape completely black

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

int main(){
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(500, 500), "hello world", sf::Style::Close);

    sf::RectangleShape rect;
    rect.setSize(sf::Vector2f(100, 100));
    rect.setFillColor(sf::Color::Red);

    sf::Shader blur;
    if (!blur.loadFromFile("blur.frag", sf::Shader::Fragment)){
        return 1;
    }
    if (!blur.isAvailable()){
        return 1;
    }
    blur.setUniform("texture", sf::Shader::CurrentTexture);
    blur.setUniform("blur_radius", 0.002f);

    while (window.isOpen()){

        sf::Event evnt;

        while (window.pollEvent(evnt)){
            if (evnt.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color(0, 100, 100));

        sf::RenderStates state;
        state.shader = &blur;
        window.draw(rect, state);

        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and my shader code.

```
uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform float blur_radius;

void main()
{
    vec2 offx = vec2(blur_radius, 0.0);
    vec2 offy = vec2(0.0, blur_radius);

    vec4 pixel = texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy)               * 4.0 +
                 texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy - offx)        * 2.0 +
                 texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy + offx)        * 2.0 +
                 texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy - offy)        * 2.0 +
                 texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy + offy)        * 2.0 +
                 texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy - offx - offy) * 1.0 +
                 texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy - offx + offy) * 1.0 +
                 texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy + offx - offy) * 1.0 +
                 texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy + offx + offy) * 1.0;

    gl_FragColor =  gl_Color * (pixel / 16.0);
}
```

I would expect a blurred red rectangle to appear in the top left cornor but instead theres a black solid rectangle.

[image: This is the result of the code above]

Comment: Please edit in a [MCVE].

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz its updated now

Comment: The shader code looks fine. There's nothing in your code though that would make a blurred red rectangle appear. You have a blue rectangle that you apply the shader to, but what do you expect? You can't just blur a single color. In order to see the blur effect you have to have something else, something you can blur the color with. Do the following as an experiment: Apply the blur shader to the entire scene and you will see it'll work as expected :)

Comment: Create a red texture, make a sprite on top of it, then draw this sprite. RectangleShape does not have a texture, so it is not affected by shader I guess.

Comment: @user3881815 woops when I had this in my original code the triangle was red. but with this minimal complete and verifiable example as bartek suggested I made the rectangle blue for some reason... I'm changing right now thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 2):

Because `rect` does not have a texture attach to it, all the pixels used in blur.frag are invalid, I guess in this case it use black pixels, hence the black rectangle.

You should [create a texture](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/graphics-draw.php#off-screen-drawing) (use `sf::RenderTexture`), draw whatever you want on it, then create a `sf::Sprite` on top of it and draw this sprite. Alternatively you may load a texture [from an image](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.4/graphics-sprite.php#loading-a-texture).

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main(){
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "hello world", sf::Style::Close);
    window.setFramerateLimit(60);

    sf::RectangleShape rectBlue;
    rectBlue.setSize(sf::Vector2f(100, 50));
    rectBlue.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
    sf::RectangleShape rectYellow;
    rectYellow.setSize(sf::Vector2f(100, 50));
    rectYellow.setFillColor(sf::Color::Yellow);
    rectYellow.setPosition(0, 50);

    sf::RenderTexture renderTexture;
    if (!renderTexture.create(100, 100)){ //create a render texture
        return 1;
    }
    renderTexture.clear();
    renderTexture.draw(rectBlue); //draw blue rect on the render texture
    renderTexture.draw(rectYellow); //draw yellow rect
    renderTexture.display();
    sf::Sprite sprite(renderTexture.getTexture()); //create a sprite from the created texture

    sf::Shader blur;
    if (!blur.loadFromFile("blur.frag", sf::Shader::Fragment)){
        return 1;
    }
    if (!blur.isAvailable()){
        return 1;
    }
    blur.setUniform("texture", sf::Shader::CurrentTexture);
    blur.setUniform("blur_radius", 0.05f);

    while (window.isOpen()){

        sf::Event evnt;

        while (window.pollEvent(evnt)){
            if (evnt.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color(0, 100, 100));
        window.draw(sprite, &blur); //draw the sprite with blur shader
        window.display();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: ty so much for your good explanation and clear answer. this have been such an annoying problem for me. but this is not actualy what I wanted... this blur shader didn't work the way I wanted. do you know how I could create a shader that blurs the outline of a sprite?

Comment: quick and dirty way: you can simply check pixel alpha `pixel.a` before assign gl_FragColor. If `pixel.a < 16.0` then blur it: `gl_FragColor =  gl_Color * (pixel / 16.0);`, else don't: `gl_FragColor =  gl_Color * texture2D(texture, gl_TexCoord[0].xy)`. If you want a transparent render texture then dont call `renderTexture.clear()`

Comment: I used most of the day but I finaly figured it out myself and in the procces I wrote my first shader program... ty so much for the help tntxtnt you gave me motivation to do my first shader program